# Putting gps waypoints into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, gpx, garmin

I've taken multiple gps waypoints and I'm hoping to put them into some sort of GIS program (atm I have GQIS as that was recommended to me) to look at them in map form, but how do I get them there?

I am using GDA94 points and a Garmin GPSMAP 64s.

I have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Great thing about QGis, it's a lot about drag & drop. Assuming you have your waypoins in any form of text file, preferably a csv-file, you can either just drag it into QGis, or you can import it straight away as a spatial layer (less work afterwards). In order to do so, just click the comma-icon to the left, navigate to your waypoint-file, choose GDA94 as your EPSG-code and make sure you choose both the correct separator and fields for X- and Y-values. No magic there.

Then save your layer as a shape-file and start editing/analysing as you like.

Also, for a more in depth tutorial, check e.g. [here](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/19-beginner-quantum-gis-tutorials/59-how-to-create-a-shapefile-from-xy-data-using-qgis.html).

In order to validate whether you did everything right, you should visually check with a basemap like OSM, which you can easily add via the QuickMap-Extension.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has as well a function to import the GPS points directly from the GPS. Check the menu toolbar for Vector - GPS - GPS tools. There you have to browse for your GPX file, which is saved on your GPS and give a directory for the file to be saved on your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Basecamp.

Load them into Basecamp and export to GPX.  Drop and drag onto a map canvas and select layer id 0 waypoints.  They will appear on the map.

Alternately you can export from Basecamp in KML format.

The export can be individual points, selected points or by Basecamp list.